# Programmatically setting unique onclicks to imgs in a loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, loops, onclick

So I have this gallery page where I have multiple `<img>` tags with a unique picture. Clicking on the picture should take you to a another webpage with more info on that specific picture. Hence, all `onclick()`s are unique, depending on the src of the image.

Now, given the fact that all these `<img>` tags are virtually same save for picture, I decided to use JavaScript to make all of them in a loop, as seen below:

**loadImageGalleryData**

```
for (var i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
    var imgSrc = "http://localhost:63342/Performance%20Task/Website/imgs/gallery/img/" + i + ".jpg";
    console.log(imgSrc);

    var imgDiv = document.createElement('div');
    imgDiv.className = "img";

    var descDiv = document.createElement('div');
    descDiv.className = "desc";

    var imgView = document.createElement('img');
    imgView.src = imgSrc;
    imgView.onclick = (function() {{openWebpage(imgSrc);}})();
    console.log(imgSrc);
    imgView.width = 300;
    imgView.height = 200;

    imgDiv.appendChild(imgView);
    imgDiv.appendChild(descDiv);
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(imgDiv);

}
```

The `openWebpage()` function in particular is this one:

**openWebpage()**

```
function openWebpage(src) {
    var orig = window.document.title;
    window.document.title = src;
    open("imagePage.html");
}
```

The imagePage has a jscript which tells ITS OWN img and div tag to display the image, whose source is received from window.document.opener.title or somethign like that.

All the images get built, but the `onclick()` doesn't register. A peek in the developer mode in Chrome, and the images don't have an `onlick()` attribute.

Also, if I change this snippet of code:

```
 imgView.onclick = (function() {{openWebpage(imgSrc);}})();
```

into this:

```
 imgView.onclick = function() {openWebpage(imgSrc);};
```

The `onlick()` DOES register, but for every image simultaneously, with the src of the last image created. So when I click on Picture 1, it goes to the information of Picture 22. Same goes for every other picture. It's all the same info.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: ADDITIONAL INFO

**imagePage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/imagePage.css"/>
<script src="jscript/imageData.js"></script>
<script src="jscript/loadImageData.js"></script>
</head>
<ul>
<li><a href="homepage.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<body>
<div>
    <h1 id="imageTitle">TESTTITLE</h1>
</div>

<div>
    <img id="imageView">
</div>

<div class="boxed" id="imageDesc">

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**loadImageData**

```
window.onload = function() {
    var imageSrc = opener.document.title;
    var imageDesc = map[imageSrc];

    var imageView = document.getElementById("imageView");
    var imageDescView = document.getElementById("imageDesc");

    imageView.src = imageSrc;
    imageDescView.innerHTML = imageDesc;
};
```

Comment: Whats in imagepage.html?

Comment: Upated it in the quetosin

Answer (score 1):

On the last iteration of your loop, you set imgSrc to the url of picture 22. So on the click event your function openWebPage fires with that url in the argument.

Comment: Wait I don't get it, for every picture on every loop iteration, I set a source

So 'imgtag1' would have src of 'img1.jpg', and 'imgtag2' would have src of 'img2.jpg'

You're correct in the fact that I set the imgSrc to 22, but that's for the 22nd picture. Is there some weird stuff when it comes to having multiple onclicks?

Comment: You are setting click event to every picture that looks like this.. onclick="openWebPage(imgSrc)" ..When that fires it looks for imgSrc, which is set to img22 from the last iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
imgView.addEventListener("click", function() {openWebpage(imgSrc);});
```